# How to wait rendering before acting on click event?

Tags: javascript, meteor, internationalization, meteor-blaze

This issue not always shows up. It works fine if I wait some time for the page to load or, if I wait enough between clicks to change the language on this drop-down menu. This is for a simple multi-language website.

My Drop-down in the nav-bar looks like:

```
    ....
    <li class="dropdown">  

    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> <img src="Pictures/BR-US-SP.png"><b class="caret"></b></a>  
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="langMenu">  
                <li><a href="#" id="pt-BR" name="pt-BR" value="pt-BR"><img src="/Pictures/1383607461_Brazil.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="en" name="en" value="en"><img src="/Pictures/1383615303_United-States.png"></a></li>  
                <li><a href="#" id="es" name="es" value="es"><img src="/Pictures/1383615325_Spain.png"></a></li>  
                <li class="divider"></li>  
            </ul>  
    </li> 
    ....
```

And events looks like:

```
Template.navigation.events({
'click #langMenu': function(event){
        currentLang = $(event.target).attr('id');
  ...
   // So some stuff with and re-renders page upon value of currentLang //
  ...
 }
});
```

When it breaks, console shows that the variable currentLang is undefined. So I am assuming that this is because the template was not rendered in time for the click event to pick up its value. Is this assumption correct?

How do I make sure to always get the currentLang value?

Sorry. I have spent a couple days already goggling it out . However as Meteor evolves so fast, I am confused by so many possible solutions I found and tested that actually did not work (deprecated?). I can't get by Meteor Docs exactly how to use Blaze functions, when and how to use onRendered, etc... Are there any good examples?

Instead, should I use a completely different approach by using Iron Router? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

You have to block that out. The current ES5 method of doing that would be

```
Template.navigation.events({
'click #langMenu': function(event){
        setTimeout(function(){
            currentLang = $(event.target).attr('id');
        },100)
 }
});
```

Comment: Hi thatgibbyguy, I tried that but I still could reproduce the error. It seems it reduces the amount of times the error occurred, bbut that's only my impression. I can't confirm it statistically. I tried also with 1000 and still could reproduce it. I was looking for something lilke "wait until target is ready" or "want until template x is rendered".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the selector for your click function. I'd do this instead :

`Template.navigation.events({
    'click #langMenu>li': function(event){
        currentLang = $(event.currentTarget).attr('id');
        // Do stuff...
     }
});`

Comment: Thanks Choy. I had like this earlier... Although I did not noticed any real change. I even tested (again) with #langMenu>li>a and still could reproduce the error.

Comment: Really? Using `event.currentTarget` as opposed to `event.target`?

Comment: I had left with ```target``` because with ```event.currentTarget``` I get ```undefined```. If I add the line ```console.log( "value of currentTarget", event.currentTarget);``` it does show ```<li><a href="#" id="es" name="es" value="es"><img src="/Pictures/1383615325_Spain.png"></a></li> ```but then I with ```console.log( "value of currentTarget", $(event.currentTarget).attr('id'));``` it gets ```undefined```

Comment: Interesting enough. I tested ```currentLang = event.target.id``` and it worked. However with ```currentLang = event.currentTarget.id``` did not. I have put an id one every HTML outer element possible and it still returned undefined. I learned that I actually don't need jQuery to get the id but still could not figure out currentTarget.

Comment: Hmmm. I'd be interested in seeing all of the code involved here.